# Tidy up fields before twig output

Tags: theming

Where to tidy up field values before they are outputted to twig in D8?

- hook_theme?
- hook_preprocess_field?
- twig extension?
- field formatter?

Comment: It's more opinion based where you like to do this. I would prefer a field formatter and if you provide config options for the UI this is the most transparent way for others to see what is going on.

Comment: In general yes. But the resulting logic might affect controller logic - so it should not sit in the view. 

For example might parameters define a library inclusion.

So a hook might be better. But is theme or preprocess better for the job?

Thanks

Comment: This is no reason to use one or the other, you can attach libraries to `$elements['#attached']` in a field formatter or in any other place you've mentioned.